# 1999 Giant Lafree Electrik, Only the diagnostic red light comes on. What is the problem?

Tags: maintenance, electric-bike, battery

When I turn the bike on, the five lights that indicate charge status flash red and then go out with only the red diagnostic light remaining lit. I ran the diagnostic checks and all items in the check were working properly.

I had the battery pack checked and the battery is fully charged and there is 24 volt output at the plug in to the bike.

What is the problem?

Comment: You're going to need to dig out the manual - clearly the electronics are complaining about something.  Do you still have the paperwork it came with when new?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by holding down on the reset button.

Update:
I should have said I held down the self-diagnosis button. It took a few seconds then I think I heard a beep and all the lights flashed then the five lights indicating a full charge came on and stayed on. I rode the bike and the lights functioned properly.

There is nothing in the manual about holding down the self-diagnosis button to reset, but I thought I would try it and it worked.

There is no specific reset button. Sorry for the incorrect initial response.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  Are you referring to the same bike/electronic component?  Where is the reset button located? How long did you hold it down?  What was the response from the unit? Did it beep or did any other sounds emanate from the unit?

Comment: Welcome to the site - Presumably you're the same person as posted the question but with a different account ?